# Capifony error when rolling back

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, rollback, capifony

I have been using Capifony to deploy my application and everything works fine. However, when there's an error during the deploy, it rolls back and the rollback fails.

```
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' rm -rf /var/www/capifony/releases/20150923104657; true"
servers: ["myserver"]
[myserver] executing command
command finished in 110ms
**failed: "sh -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/capifony/releases/20150923104657 && SYMFONY_ENV=prod /usr/local/bin/composer.phar install --no-dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress'\\'''" on myserver**
```

Then the error on the browser is:

> Compile Error: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required '/mnt/app/www/capifony/releases/20150923104657/src/MyApp/CoreBundle/MyAppCoreBundle.php' (include_path='/mnt/app/www/capifony/shared/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:/mnt/app/www/capifony/shared/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/mnt/app/www/capifony/shared/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/mnt/app/www/capifony/shared/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

From what I understand, it tries to do a composer install on the 20150923104657 release. However, this is the version it just deleted (rm -rf /var/www/capifony/releases/20150923104657). So it's normal that it fails. But I don't understand why it does that on this order.

Could anybody help me?

EDIT:

My Capfile:

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

require 'capifony_symfony2'
```

My deploy.rb:

set :application,                    "myapp"

```
set :deploy_to,                      "/var/www/capifony"
set :app_path,                      "app"
set :repository,                     "https://git-myapp@github.com/Myapp/myapp.git"
set :scm,                              :git
set :branch,                          "master"
set :model_manager,           "doctrine"
set :symfony_env_prod,      "prod"

#recette
role :web,                    "myserver"
role :app,                    "myserver", :primary => true

set :use_sudo,                     true
set :user,                             "ubuntu"
set :keep_releases,             10
set :assets_install,                true
set :dump_assetic_assets,     true
set :use_composer,              true
set :composer_bin,               "/usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
set :update_vendors,            false             # false = install mode
set :clear_controllers,            false
set :shared_files,                  ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,            [app_path + "/logs", app_path + "/Resources/images/myimages",   web_path + "/media", web_path + "/zip", web_path + "/temp", "vendor"]
set :deploy_via,                    :remote_cache
set :writable_dirs,                 ["app/cache", "app/logs" , "app/../web", "app/Resources/images/myimages"]
set :webserver_user,          "www-data"
set :permission_method,       :chown
set :use_set_permissions,     true

logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL

before "deploy", "maintenance_enable", "cron_stop", "permissions_capifony", "finalize_update"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup", "others_tasks", "cron_start"
before "symfony:cache:warmup", "symfony:doctrine:schema:update"
```

I can also add the detail of the tasks if it is necessary.

Comment: Could you copy your Gemfile/Capfile and your custom stages here to help the investigation ?

Comment: I'll edit my question to add these infos @Harijoe

Comment: Can you try with `set :update_vendors, true` ? I find very suspicious to have a shared vendor file between your release that you don't update.

Comment: @Harijoe I just tried with set :update_vendors, true and I keep getting the same error.